# Software to visualize Data Structures and Algorithms?

Tags: algorithms, data-structure

Is there some website or some software on which I can visualize data structures and algorithms? I have found a visualizer for sorting algorithms on [HackerEarth](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/sorting/bubble-sort/visualize/), but I need a visualizer for advanced algorithms, mostly for trees and graphs.

I need a free software. I am a student, so if some software has free licenses for students, please recommend.

This is my config:

- OS - `Windows 10`
- Ram - `16GB`
- Processor - `i7-8750H`
- Graphics Card - `gtx-1050ti`

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Especially missing: what OS should the software run on, and what is your price limit when it comes to paid solutions?

Comment: He he ...[bubble-sort, illustrated by Hungarian folk dance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lyZQPjUT5B4&edufilter=NULL)  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think if you ask about a free framework running on Windows, that can be used to visualize all sort of things you have mentioned, the best approach would be to program the visualization using some programming languages. One of such frameworks is [DataMelt](https://jwork.org/dmelt): (1) it's free (if no access to examples is needed); (2) It's based on Java and runs on Windows (3) It has a large number of 2D/3D canvaces to program grahs, charts etc. You can also use Python to program your visualization.

Answer (score 0):

[Dia](https://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Dia) lets you draw diagrams by hand, of various types.

[This page](http://svetlana.nfshost.com/wiki/irc/freenode/channels/about/uml/) lists ArgoUML and Umbrello as freedom-respecting software for UML diagram creation.

If you're interested in automatic reading of code to automatically generate a diagram, please let me know which language (C, Python, etc) in a comment and I can add something useful for it to the list.